# Get Element from Array

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Firstly sorry If I didn't write the title correct because I really cant explain it that good.

Okay so I'm making a twitter app and I used this code

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('MY PRIVATE CODE', 'MY PRIVATE CODE',     $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_secret']);
}

$home_timeline = $twitteroauth->get('/statuses/user_timeline');
print_r($home_timeline);
```

I connected it with my twitter account and this isn't the full code, part of it. So this echos.

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [created_at] => Wed Oct 10 19:27:42 +0000 2012 [id] => 256113796215603202 [id_str] => 256113796215603202 [text] => Testing a few thing on my twitter app. ) )

And it prints a few other stuff in the array but I cut it. How do I get the value of the text from the array text? Where it says [text] I would like to have the value of it?

I've spent atleast 30 minutes searching and I couldn't find the answer. If it is a simple function already made by php then can you please tell me. If it is a long line of code can you tell me.

Comment: `echo $home_timeline[0]->text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting tripped up on the fact that you have an array with an object in it. when you access the array[0] you are now interacting with an Object.

the print_r is showing you that [text] is not an index in the array so:

array['text'] does not exist. [text] is a property of the stdObject.

so to get the text it would just be $yourArray[0]->text.

note: if you put your print_r or var_dumps between <pre> </pre> tags then they will look better and be less confusing

Answer (score 0):

first convert the `object` into an array like,

```
 $array = (array) $home_timeline[0];
```

then access your array keys, by using [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
   $keys = array_keys($array);
```

Comment: I believe OP is looking to access the value. Your code will only return `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple statuses in the `$home_timeline` you would do something like this:

```
foreach($home_timeline as $status) {
    $hereBeYourText = $status->text;
}
```

Or is there something else you want to achieve?